# Set selected option to multiple select jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Hi all here's my sample code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdownA">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdownB">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdownC">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]+"  option[value="+i+"]").attr('selected','selected');
    }
```

I would expect that in dropdown A is selected 1, in dropdown B is selected 2 and in dropdown C is selected 3 but nothing happens. Where's the error?
This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/1/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `:` is not the same as `;` - Check this http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/6/

Comment: You can simplify the loop body to `$("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]).val(i+1);`.

Comment: See my answer with working demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jquery Code:-

```
 $("select").each(function(i, sel) {
     $(sel).find("option:eq(" + i + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
 });
```

in above example you don't need array...

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/12/

and if still you want to use your own code then use below given code...

code:-

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]).find("option[val="+(i+1)+"]").attr('selected','selected');
}
```

see the working example:-

http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/7/

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1) you used a `:` instead of a `;` after the declaration of the array `indexDropDown`

2) you used a zero-based indexer to loop through the array while the values start with 1; therefor add 1 to `i` when looping

3) you updated the `value` attribute while in html you used the `val` attribute, so update that one instead of `value`

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]+"  option[val="+(i+1)+"]").attr('selected','selected');
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/4/)**

Comment: I don't think that playing the "spot the difference" game is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hey earlier it was error in you code

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]+"  option[value="+i+"]").attr('selected','selected');
    }
```

You have applied ":" instead of ";" I think now it will work

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your first line ends in a `:` instead of a `;`, so the array value isn't assigned.
2. Your for loop is 0-index, but the values you want to assign are 1,2, and 3. For i = 0, you need value = 1, for i = 1, value = 2, and for i = 2, value = 3.

Updated Code:

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]+"  option[val="+(i+1)+"]").attr('selected','selected');
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vn75P/1/)

A helpful tip: check the browser console when you're running the script. That's how I found the `:`. It's easy to miss just reading the script. In chrome, hit `F12` and click `console` to see javascript errors on the page you're on.

Answer (score 0):

You've ended the first line with a colon which causes a syntax error.

As well as this, your `<option>` tags have `val` attributes instead of `value` attributes.

Finally, because you're iterating from 0 to 2, and your values are listed from 1 to 3, you'll need to use `i+1` when selecting the elements.

To achieve the behaviour you desire you can correct the attributes and make a couple of minor changes to the JavaScript.

```
var indexDropDown = ["A","B","C"];
for (var i = 0; i < indexDropDown.length; i++) {
    $("#dropdown"+indexDropDown[i]+"  option[value="+(i+1)+"]").attr('selected','selected');
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/9/).